# Why is the context not passed to eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, dom

At the moment i am doing a simple to do application, and i am just accessing the dom and adding some eventlisteners, the thing is, i have a class that is applied in 3 buttons, and i want to add the event listener to 3 of them, but i want to reuse a function to show and hide a modal.

Basicly when i click in one of those buttons with the class applied i want to show the modal

**So i did this:**

```
var showBackdrop = document.querySelector('.backdrop');
var showModal = document.querySelector('.modal');
var confirmationNo = document.querySelector('.modal__confirmation--no')

var planChoices = document.querySelectorAll('.plan__choice');

function showModal() {
    showBackdrop.style.display = 'block';
    showModal.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideModal() {
    showBackdrop.style.display = 'none';
    showModal.style.display = 'none';
}

var ctx = this;
for(planChoice of planChoices) {
    console.log(ctx);
    planChoice.addEventListener('click', function() {

    });
}

confirmationNo.addEventListener('click',function() {
    hideModal();
})
```

the issue is that it can't find the showModal function, the error shows, showModal is not a function,why? :S

Comment: ShowModal is defined as a variable as well ? Please try changing the name of either the variable or the function.

Comment: you are right, was thinking in other hard stuffs that i forgot the easy ones :D, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same name `showModal` for function and variable in same execution context which might the issue.